# row lines for flex container css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**pure css only!!**

I have a `div` element used as a flex container with wrap, containing elements displayed in 4 columns. I need to display lines between the rows inside that container.

I set the `border-bottom` property for each of the flex elements inside, but this makes the line of the last row to take as much elements that are in that row.

Is there any way to make the last element in container display the line until the end of the row, without making its width grow?

Or any other idea to deal with this?

**note:** the amount of elements in container is dynamic, so I don't know how many elements are in the last row.

**html**

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="element">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="element">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
 </div>
 ....
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
 margin: 10px;
 border: 3px solid green;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 30px;
}
```

demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfhLw1dh/

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one trick or hack whatever you say like:

Give `border-bottom: 1px solid green;` to `#container` and `margin-bottom: -1px;` to `.element`.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.element {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfhLw1dh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

A positioned pseudo-element could manage that too:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.element:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  /* Look it's automatic */
  width: 2000px;
  /* or some really large value */
}
.content {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have used a fixed width for that pseudo element, that doesn't answer the fact that number of elements in container is dynamic. and sure it doesn't help for responsiveness needs.